# Read in a number and print ASCII alfa character (a-z,A-Z).or print closest (in ASCII table) alfa character

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

*Read in a number and check if the corresponding ASCII character is an alfa character (a-z,A-Z). If so, print out the alfa character, if not print closest (in ASCII table) alfa character.*

so if i input: **71**, the results = **G**
so if i input: **92**, the results = **** **but** print the nearest alpha character which is = **Z**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why do you tag your question from 2.0 to 4.0?

Comment: If you want help with your homework, please [edit] your question to show what you've come up with so far, and explain why it isn't working the way you expected it to. See also [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 1):

```
        public static char GetNearestAsciiAlpha(int inputNum)
        {
            int alphaNum;
            if (inputNum <=93)
            {
                alphaNum = Math.Clamp(inputNum, 65, 90);
            }
            else
            {
                alphaNum = Math.Clamp(inputNum, 97, 122);
            }
            return Convert.ToChar(alphaNum);
        }
```

Comment: hello, welcome to stackoverflow, it would be very useful if you could add a description and explanation on the posted answer!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).